# How to configure Laravel paths?

Tags: laravel

I'm a trying to install Laravel
My problem is:

/localhost/laravel displays its content like the folders under it.

but I am expecting something like the logo of laravel and the text "You have arrived."

I believe that the error is something in my paths.php:

```
return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we just defined the path to the application directory. Most likely
| you will never need to change this value as the default setup should
| work perfectly fine for the vast majority of all our applications.
|
*/

'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Public Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The public path contains the assets for your web application, such as
| your JavaScript and CSS files, and also contains the primary entry
| point for web requests into these applications from the outside.
|
*/

'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The base path is the root of the Laravel installation. Most likely you
| will not need to change this value. But, if for some wild reason it
| is necessary you will do so here, just proceed with some caution.
|
*/

'base' => __DIR__.'/..',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Storage Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The storage path is used by Laravel to store cached Blade views, logs
| and other pieces of information. You may modify the path here when
| you want to change the location of this directory for your apps.
|
*/

'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',

 );
```

and index.php

```
 require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';


 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';


 $app->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your path. You should create a virtual host and point the virtual host's root to `laravel/public`.